# Responsive iframe using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am using Bootstrap.

I have a text which contains 2 or 3 iframes based embed videos.

This data is fetched from database.

How can I make these iframes responsive?

**Example Code:**

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

     SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT
     SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT

     <iframe src="http://youtube.com/...."></iframe>

     SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT
     SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT

     <iframe src="http://youtube.com/...."></iframe>


     SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT
     SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT

     <iframe src="http://youtube.com/...."></iframe> 

   </div>

</div>
```

This is a dynamic data. How can I make it responsive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an iframe responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive)

Comment: It's good to note which version of Bootstrap. I've answered this with two options.

Answer (score 223):

### Option 1

With Bootstrap 3.2 you can wrap each iframe in the responsive-embed wrapper of your choice:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

### Option 2

If you don't want to wrap your iframes, you can use FluidVids https://github.com/toddmotto/fluidvids. See demo here: http://toddmotto.com/labs/fluidvids/

```
   <!-- fluidvids.js -->
    <script src="js/fluidvids.js"></script>
    <script>
    fluidvids.init({
      selector: ['iframe'],
      players: ['www.youtube.com', 'player.vimeo.com']
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: unable decrease height of `iframe`. I changed from `100%` to `80%` class `.embed-responsive iframe`. But is giving empty space. after the video. How to avoid this space.

Comment: FINALLY this works perfectly!  It might be nice to include the obligatory `<p>Your browser does not appear to support iframes</p>` between the `iframe` tags, but I'm wondering if that's even relevant these days...thanks again, many (hacky) solutions were close, but this is perfect!

Comment: to Option 1: the url to the docs changed to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#responsive-embed

Comment: use one aspect ratio and include this to get it work-->> <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

and within iframe tag --> frameborder="0"
    style="overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
    "height="100%"
    width="100%"

Comment: The URL changes depending on the version of Bootstrap. Currently referred to as Embeds. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/embed/

Answer (score 33):

Please, Check this out, I hope it's help

```
<div class="row">
 <iframe class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" src="http://www.w3schools.com">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Ugh finally something simple that actually works.

Answer (score 20):

The best solution that worked great for me.

You have to:
Copy this code to your main CSS file,

```
.responsive-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 60px; overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-video iframe,
.responsive-video object,
.responsive-video embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then put your embeded video to

```
<div class="responsive-video">
    <iframe ></iframe>
</div>
```

That’s it! Now you can use responsive videos on your site.

Comment: `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` make some weird stuff

Answer (score 10):

So, youtube gives out the iframe tag as follows:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2EIeUlvHAiM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my case, i just changed it to width="100%" and left the rest as is. It's not the most elegant solution (after all, in different devices you'll get weird ratios) But the video itself does not get deformed, just the frame.

Comment: Is it responsive that way? If it is, will it keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: Nice and simple.  Worked for me!  Thanks!

Comment: Works for me too. Keeping the suggested height (in your case 315), but change the width to "100%". Scales responsivly and works well with the bootstrap column classes.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 3**

To update current iframe

```
$("iframe").wrap('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"/>');
$("iframe").addClass('embed-responsive-item');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below syntax to make iframes responsive in Bootstrap 5:

```html
<div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
  <iframe src="LinkHere" title="YouTube video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Aspect ratios other than 16x9:

```html
<div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
  <div>1x1</div>
</div>
<div class="ratio ratio-4x3">
  <div>4x3</div>
</div>
<div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
  <div>16x9</div>
</div>
<div class="ratio ratio-21x9">
  <div>21x9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Working during August 2020

use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

use one aspect ratio

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

within iframe use options

```
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."
  frameborder="0"
    style="
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
    "
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
  ></iframe>
```