# making an iframe responsive that is inside a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to  make iframe responsive for all screen.

```
  <div class="iframe-class">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PZEwPJzMKGg"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Comment: try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228056/responsive-iframe-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Make iframe responsive for all screen

This will work for you sure.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PZEwPJzMKGg"></iframe>
  </div>
```

[Refrence Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_responsive_embed&stacked=h)

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap 3.2 you can wrap each iframe in the responsive-embed wrapper of your choice:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

Reference:
[Responsive iframe using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228056/responsive-iframe-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PZEwPJzMKGg"></iframe>
  </div>

  <!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PZEwPJzMKGg"></iframe>
  </div>
```