# Mobile browser not scaling responsive website

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I made a lot of responsive websites, but I've never encountered this problem. I made a responsive portfolio website and if I resize my desktop browser it scales fine. It uses bootstrap for the grid. And some scroll effect libraries but they don't seem to affect the scaling because I tried it with javascript off. But when I open it on a real smartphone it just doesn't scale down, it views it in a zoomed out desktop view. Things i've tried:

- Adding all kinds of viewport "meta tags" like: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
- Checking my styles, if there is something forcing the body width to be wider
- Turning off javascript

Nothing seems to work, if someone can look in to it and see what i've been missing that would be great!

http://www.nielsgerritsen.com

It scales fine in resized desktop browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your website is within a frame. Your actual website: http://www.carehr.nl/nielsgerritsen works fine on a mobile, however you have specifically added `noresize` to your frame `<frame name="main" src="http://www.carehr.nl/nielsgerritsen" scrolling="auto" noresize="">`

I would suggest you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive) if you're planning to continue hosting the website within a frame.

Comment: Thank you! I think it is because my website is in a subdirectory at a shared host plan. I will take a look in to the link you posted.