# Responsive youtube video with iframe

Tags: css

I have a following iframe in html and that contain youtube video. here is the iframe:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I make this iframe responsive?

Comment: Please refer this -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an intrinsic ratio. The containing element is responsive and stays at a specific aspect ratio. The iframe inside is positioned absolutely to this element.

HTML

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

More info on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/wbjkuwym/

```
iframe, object, embed {
        max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; /*315/420=0.75*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div iframe{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use aspect-ratio CSS property

The aspect-ratio CSS property allows you to define the desired width-to-height ratio of an element's box. This means that even if the parent container or viewport size changes, the browser will adjust the element's dimensions to maintain the specified width-to-height ratio. The specified aspect ratio is used in the calculation of auto sizes and some other layout functions.

Create the css rule

```css
      .aspect-video {
          aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
        }
```

Add this css class add to class propierty in iframe tag and change width to width="100%"

```html
     <iframe
        class="aspect-video"
        width="100%"
        src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`}
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share fullscreen"
        allowFullScreen
      ></iframe>
```