# Multiple Iframes on one page scaling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I'm trying to put two responsive `iframes` on top of each other on one page.
Unfortunately the content of the `iframe` is resizing right but height of the iframe boarder doesn't change so there is an increasing cap between the two iframes when you re-size the window. I hope you can see what I mean. What can I do to avoid that gap?

```js
function adjustIframes() {
  $('iframe').each(function() {
    var
      $this = $(this),
      proportion = $this.data('proportion'),
      w = $this.attr('width'),
      actual_w = $this.width();

    if (!proportion) {
      proportion = $this.attr('height') / w;
      $this.data('proportion', proportion);
    }

    if (actual_w != w) {
      $this.css('height', Math.round(actual_w * proportion) + 'px');
    }
  });
}
$(window).on('resize load', adjustIframes);
```

```css
iframe {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<center>T E S T T O P</center>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="600" src="http://danielsalaw.de/Bilder/Melli/indexRev.html" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="600" src="http://danielsalaw.de/Bilder/Kocha/indexRev.html" width="100%"></iframe>
<center>T E S T B O T T O M</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add wrapper elements to make iframes responsive (at least without a javascript hack).

Here is a working example without the javascript (don't need it):

```css
    iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .wrap {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 52.68%;
      padding-top: 30px;
      height: 0;
      overflow: auto;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; //<<--- THIS IS THE KEY
      border: solid black 1px;

    }
```

```html
    <center>T E S T T O P</center>
    <div class="wrap">
      <iframe frameborder="0" src="http://danielsalaw.de/Bilder/Melli/indexRev.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <iframe frameborder="0" src="http://danielsalaw.de/Bilder/Kocha/indexRev.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <center>T E S T B O T T O M</center>
```

The only catch here is that you need to know the aspect ratio you want for the iframe. Basically here i just took the heigh and divided by the width of you original iframe (=52.68%) and then used that in the padding hack.

Basically taken from this answer on making iframes responsive:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27836998/900271

Answer (score -1):

IFrame heights can be a pain because the content inside the iframe is laid out independently of the parent so it you can't really style it with CSS and get the height to adjust (as Oke Henrik Skogstream said).

If you don't know the height of the iframe content then you'll have to hack it with javascript from *inside* the iframe.

See here for a simple JavaScript hack: https://github.com/jcharlesworthuk/reactive.iframes