# Fit an Absolute positioned html to an iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

How do I fit an absolute positioned html to an iframe? I need this to make it responsive to the browser. I know that it should be created using media queries but it was created using absolute positioning by using some online html tools.

So my plan is using an iframe that would resize based on the browsers width and height. Then the content inside would be scaled depending on the iframe's size.

I already tried this one

```
<iframe width="1024" height="768" src="http://www.bbc.com" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
```

But it didn't worked.

The html inside the iframe has a size of 1920x1080. The iframe has a size of 1600x900. I need to fit the 1920x1080 inside that 1600x900 so i need to scale it down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Comment: The solutions there doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle of this problem?

Comment: But what you have works .. in Chrome I tried

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/suf1fnmd/

Comment: The iframe shouldn't have scroll bars and the html inside the iframe should scale to fit in the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iframe` width/height needs to match its source widht/height settings if you don't want the scroll bar to appear, so I changed it to 1950px/1110 (some margin included).

It the scroll bar still appears (content is bigger than iframe), you would normally use `overflow: hidden`, though it is not yet fully cross browser, but adding `scrolling=no` to the `iframe` markup is.

```css
.wrap { width: 480px; height: 270px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.frame {
  -ms-zoom: 0.25;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.frame.nr1 { width: 1950px; height: 1110px; border: 1px solid black; }
.frame.nr2 { width: 1920px; height: 1080px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<p>iframe with wider/higher settings</p>
<div class="wrap">
  <iframe class="frame nr1" src="https://www.htechcorp.net/sandbox/sample.html"></iframe>
</div>
<p>iframe using `scrolling=no`</p>
<div class="wrap">
  <iframe scrolling=no class="frame nr2" src="https://www.htechcorp.net/sandbox/sample.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Some kinda, but the the image should be fitted in the iframe it should not be scrolled to view the other parts of the image.

Comment: @Kiel Updated, now it does. The ifame were set to 1280 but the iframe source was 1920, so I updated iframe to 1920

Comment: Regarding css scale, is there a computation for this? because i will be dynamically setting the width and height of the wrapper.

Comment: @Kiel Will you set width/height dynamically in the markup?

Comment: it will dynamically change once the user resizes the window.

Comment: @Kiel If the wrapper's aspect ratio change, you need to re-compute the percent during the resize event and update the CSS rule

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103951/discussion-between-kiel-and-lgson).

Answer (score 0):

This code makes your iframe responsible

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18801404/4334348)

```
iframe, object, embed {
        max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The html inside the iframe has a size of 1920x1080. The iframe has a size of 1600x900. I need to fit the 1920x1080 inside that 1600x900 so i need to scale it down.