# iframe needs to be minimized for mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, mobile

I am currently building a site at [www.georound.com](http://georound.com) and when you click on the pin on the map an infoWindow pops up with a video embedded inside using an iframe. 
My problem is these videos look great on desktop but once I try and open the page on mobile the iframe is too big and doesnt resize for mobile, the infoWindow itself does resize and looks good on mobile.

I have tried changing the css for the iframe but every time I make it smaller for mobile it gets smaller on desktop too!!

When I open the infoWindow on mobile with the phone turned sideways, the display is ok too.  Its just when the screen is small that the iframe doesnt resize correctly.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive

Comment: I tried a few of the css changes on the link above but when I do it within an iframes alone it works but if I then put that iframes in an infoWindow, nothing shows up!!! You can see what I mean at www.georound.com            the video at the bottom is in an iframe and resizes for each device but theven video within the infoWindows uses the same code and comes up blank???

Comment: It seems like position: absolute; is giving the trouble with the infoWindow.  Just shows up as blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@media` in your css to define at what size screen you want certain CSS rules to apply.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 iframe {
   width: 50vw;
 }
}
```