# Responsive iframe for different aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive, aspect-ratio

I followed this post [Making an iframe responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive) to make iframes responsive.

```
# A test case
<div class="intrinsic-container">
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="640" height="498" src="https://v.qq.com/iframe/player.html?vid=y0379t92gl9&tiny=0&auto=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

# style.css
.intrinsic-container {
    position: relative;
    /* padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-bottom:75%; /* 4:3 */
    /* padding-bottom: 66.66%; /* 3:2 */
    /* padding-top: 25px; */
    height: 0;
}

.intrinsic-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It works. My question is how to make iframes responsive for different aspect ratios of content areas, such as

- YouTube video: `width="560" height="315"`, the ratio is `16:9`
- `width="640" height="498"`, the ratio is `4:3`

Comment: It seems to be working fine with a youtube video - https://jsfiddle.net/eo8fwwjs/

Comment: @Pangloss, yup, it works after clearing caches in my machine. Do you have ideas to make them work for different aspect ratios?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Aspect ratios of what? Based on what condition?

Comment: You just need to use different classes, e.g. `.intrinsic-container-16x9 {padding-bottom:56.25%;}` and `.intrinsic-container-4x3 {padding-bottom:75%;}` etc.

Comment: @Pangloss, thx for ur constant help. If I embed a video with `4:3`, which one should I use, `<div class="intrinsic-container">` or `<div class="intrinsic-container-4x3">`?

Comment: That would be `4x3`, you can assign both classes if you want it's up to how you want to organize the style.