# How do I make the iframe resolution responsive to fully fit the iframe that it is in?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

[iframe-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vXLf.png)

The image shows to iframes, sometimes I need to show 3 iframes.

My goal is to make it so that the iframes are all responsive inside.

Here is my current css styling:

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: check about resposive iframes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive check the link for responsive iframes.

Answer (score 0):

you can like this:

if you have class,you can delete,the src is the page you want to display

```
    <iframe class="" src="" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I already have it that way, the problem is that I can't get website inside of the iframe to fully expand and go fullscreen inside

Comment: the 100% it mean's the first src take all the page.