# Iframe, maintain original css inside it

Tags: css, iframe, responsive

I have the following situation. I've a html page with some graphs on it. If you open it on desktop device, you see graphs side-by-side. If you open it on mobile, you see one graph below other. This pages has it's own CSS.

I need to load this page inside other page, using iframe or object's tag. My problem is when I include it inside a iframe, lose the response has originally. So, now, If open the page (that has the original html in a frame) on mobile device, I see graphs side-by-side, instead the mobile view.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue? I tried to include in the new page the same CSS on head tag but the behavior remains the same.

Regards,

Comment: Try the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive

Answer (score 0):

I added the line below in head tag and now is working. Thanks,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Regards,