# Is there anyway to make an iFrame responsive without adding any code to the parent page?

Tags: html, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm producing a page that will reside inside an iFrame. Below is the code that mine will drop into.  It needs to be responsive, which mine is.  However, the iFrame is not.  I don't have access to the parent or hosting page in order to implement solutions that I've seen suggested. Is there a way to make the iFrame responsive ***without adding to the parent code?***

To me, this seems the most logical answer (IF I had access to the parent source code) - http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/.  But, I don't, so was wanting to know if there is a way to do within my code which resides in the src="https://..." of the .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an iframe responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive)

Comment: Please post your code so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, their are many security restrictions In the browser to stop you doing this.

Their is a longer answer that involves proxying, but then your into potential legal problems. It would be better to just get the other site to agree to you doing this and if they won’t then you should not really be doing it in the first place.